# Liberty Docker Image is not running

Tags: docker, websphere-liberty

When I try to run the docker image I am getting this error:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from 
daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: 
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused 
\"exec: \\\"/opt/ibm/docker/docker-server\\\": 
stat /opt/ibm/docker/docker-server: no such file or 
directory\"\n".**
```

I have installed Docker on Windows-10 along with `Docker Tool Box`. I have created a small Spring Web application and I want to run this application using Liberty profile.

I have built the docker image using below docker file.

```
FROM ibmjava:8-jre


RUN apt-get update \
        && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends unzip \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install WebSphere Liberty
ENV LIBERTY_VERSION 16.0.0_04


ARG LIBERTY_URL

ARG DOWNLOAD_OPTIONS=""

RUN LIBERTY_URL=${LIBERTY_URL:-$(wget -q -O - https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/downloads/wlp/index.yml  | grep $LIBERTY_VERSION -A 6 | sed -n 's/\s*kernel:\s//p' | tr -d '\r' )}  \
        && wget $DOWNLOAD_OPTIONS $LIBERTY_URL -U UA-IBM-WebSphere-Liberty-Docker -O /tmp/wlp.zip \
        && unzip -q /tmp/wlp.zip -d /opt/ibm \
        && rm /tmp/wlp.zip

ENV PATH=/opt/ibm/wlp/bin:$PATH

# Set Path Shortcuts
ENV LOG_DIR=/logs \
        WLP_OUTPUT_DIR=/opt/ibm/wlp/output

RUN mkdir /logs \
        && ln -s $WLP_OUTPUT_DIR/defaultServer /output \
        && ln -s /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer /config

# Configure WebSphere Liberty

RUN /opt/ibm/wlp/bin/server create \
        && rm -rf $WLP_OUTPUT_DIR/.classCache /output/workarea

#COPY docker-server /opt/ibm/docker/

EXPOSE 9080 9443

CMD ["/opt/ibm/docker/docker-server", "run", "defaultServer"]
```

Comment: What's the output of `docker run --rm <your_image> ls -l /opt/ibm` ?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 Nov 29 23:42 java
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 Dec 16 23:54 wlp

Comment: @AlexandreFILLATRE when I run above command got below output.
docker run --rm c3c03703f6ad ls -l /opt/ibm
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 Nov 29 23:42 java
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 Dec 16 23:54 wlp

Comment: In your Dockerfile, the `COPY docker-server /opt/ibm/docker/` line is commented out. According to the `ls` result, the `/opt/ibm/docker/docker-server` is effectively not present on your system. Should this file be installed from the previous image steps ?

Comment: @AlexandreFILLATRE yes your right after uncommenting that line and having docer-server file resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I added it as an answer, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to un-comment the `COPY docker-server /opt/ibm/docker/` line, then it'll work as expected.